# Get lat-lng from google map intent

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am new comer in android world. Trying to get current co-ordinates from google map. I have done a sample app which opens google map as intent (from android website). What i want to do is get the lat-lng from that intent. I have done so far-

```
   public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
       // mMap = googleMap;
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:latitude,longitude?z=17");
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I know I can get current co-ordinate in android.
But I would like to get co-ordinate from google map intent (currenlty showing marker position)?

Comment: what do you mean by get lat-lng from starting intent.. you want to set lat and long to starting intent or what?

Comment: @bharat - I've updated my question.

Comment: I dont think so you can get Google Maps application marker/s details to your application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [`GoogleMap` class documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#getMyLocation()):

> public final Location **getMyLocation ()**
>   ...
>
> Returns the currently
>   displayed user location, or null if there is no location data
>   available.
>
> Returns
>
> - The currently displayed user location.
>
> Throws
>
> - IllegalStateException   if the my-location layer is not enabled.

Then again it also says:

> This method is deprecated. use
>   com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi instead.

So you can use `getMyLocation()` if you really want but it's not recommended. And it might return null. Or throw an exception.

The code would then be something like:

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // mMap = googleMap;
        Location myLocation;             

        try {
            myLocation = googleMap.getMyLocation();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // Handle the exception.
        }

        if (!myLocation == null) {
            // Do something with the location if it's not null...
        }
        else {
            // Handle the null location.
        }

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("geo:latitude,longitude?z=17");
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```